# Is there a Website that can convert Javascript into AMP Html (Shopify Inquiry)

Tags: javascript, shopify, amp-html, shopify-app

Plugin: [Shopsheriff](https://shopsheriff.com/)

**Problem**: My AMP page won't allow me to add my "Newsletter Sign Up" because the "Newsletter Sign Up" is Javascript. The Javascript is currently incompatible with AMP.

- I am not experienced in coding which is why I need a converter of some type to change the code

**Desired Results**: I would like to convert / change my "Newsletter Sign Up" Javascript into AMP HTML compatible script.

If you could help me in any kind of way I would be extremely grateful!

Here is the code:

```
//Some variable sets
var otgServerpath = "https://onetapsignup.com/otg/";
var otgSettings;
var otgPageURL = window.location.href;
var otgShopURL = Shopify.shop;

if(typeof($otjq) == 'undefined' ){
    if (typeof(window.jQuery) == 'undefined') {
        (function() {
            // Load jquery script if doesn't exist
            var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
            script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.onload = function() {
                $otjq = window.jQuery;  // $otjq is our jQuery
                $ = window.jQuery;  // $otjq is our jQuery
                loadOneTapGoogle();
            };
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        })();
    }else{
        if (typeof(window.jQuery.ajax) == 'undefined') {
            (function() {
                // Load jquery script if doesn't exist
                var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
                script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.onload = function() {
                    $otjq = window.jQuery;  // $otjq is our jQuery
                    $ = window.jQuery;  // $otjq is our jQuery
                    loadOneTapGoogle();
                };
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
            })();
        }else{
            $otjq = window.jQuery;  // $otjq is our jQuery
            $ = window.jQuery;  // $otjq is our jQuery
            loadOneTapGoogle();  
        }               
    }
}

var otgSettingsGlobal;
function loadOneTapGoogle(argument) {
    //otgPostAjax();
    $otjq.ajax({
         url:  otgServerpath + 'ajax_get_settings.php',
         dataType: "json",
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
             'domain': otgShopURL,
             'page_url': otgPageURL,
             'theme_id': Shopify.theme.id,
             'theme_store_id': Shopify.theme.theme_store_id
         },
         error: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
         },
         success: function (otgSettings) {
            otgSettingsGlobal = otgSettings;
            otgPostAjax(otgSettings);
         }
     });
}

function otgPostAjax(otgSettings) {
    // Add One Tap Google Iframe

    if (otgSettingsGlobal.flag == 1) {
        var otgIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        otgIframe.id = 'otg_iframe';
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            var mob = 1;
            otgIframe.style = 'width: 100%; height: 380px; position: fixed;bottom: 0px;left: 0px; border: none; z-index: 2147483647; background: transparent;';
        }else{
            var mob = 2;
            otgIframe.style = 'width: 450px; height: 600px; position: fixed;top: 0px;right: 0px; border: none; z-index: 2147483647; background: transparent;';
        }
         /*
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            var mob = 1;
            otgIframe.style = 'opacity: 0;width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; bottom: 0px;left: 0px; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;background: #0d0d0dc4';
        }else{
            var mob = 2;
            otgIframe.style = 'opacity: 0;width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px;right: 0px; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;background: #0d0d0dc4';
        }*/
        otgIframe.src = otgServerpath + 'otg.php?mob='+mob+'&store_id=' + otgSettingsGlobal.store_id;
        
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(otgIframe);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#otg_iframe").css("opacity","1");
        },2000)
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            if (typeof event.data === 'string' && event.data.startsWith("onetap_")) {
                //console.log("Its string and onetap");
                $("#otg_iframe").remove();
            }
        });
        /*$("body").on("click",function(){
            $("#otg_iframe").remove();
        });*/
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you better ask the APP developers to provide the code that is compatible with AMP, after all, you use the APP service free or paid?

Comment: @Onkar The app is free and I have consulted with the APP developers but they are still working on it. I just want to speed up the process if possible. Thank you for your input! :)